# No iron for your fair-folk maiden? (Part 2: Radioactive metals)

Tags: biology, magic, creature-design, xenobiology

For reference, here is part 1 [No Iron for your fair-folk maiden? (Part 1)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/147441/46406)

A brief recap. My fair-folk are weak to all metals, but each metal has their own specific effects. The last question resulted in alkaline metals being mutagenic to them, in addition to being very harmful, just like they are to us.

So, we have the alkaline metals down, now we need to address the radioactive materials. So the question here is this: how can radioactive metals power up my fair-folk while also rapidly killing them?

Also, if anyone has any ideas on how to make the lanthanides affect my fair-folk I would appreciate it. Not necessarily part of the question, but bonus points!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Allow me to throw out the most obvious answer**

**Power-up:** The radioactive metals act like [adrenaline](https://youtu.be/HHW2VCbrMYg?t=153) in way *Red Bull* wishes it did.  Their eyes glow.  Their teeth (which are now a grimacing grin) glow.  Their hair glows.  And your throat was cut long before you actually noticed any of that.  What the radiation, borne by the metals, is doing is breaking down the sugar *really fast* in their bloodstream.

**Rapid-death:** Which is *cool,* until they [burst into flame!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT2r0DpiKBs)  This is basically a [sugar explosion](https://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/edible-innovations/sugar-explode.htm).

---

***Bonus points!***

The Lanthanides react with oxygen.

**Power-up:** There isn't one, this is a serious power-down.  The lanthanides form oxides really fast, meaning they're *robbing* the body and blood stream of oxygen.  The lanthides are the worst form of Kryptonite.

**Rapid-death:** A form of suffocation.  Your fair folk would die gasping for every cubic milliliter of air they could get into their lungs, all to no avail.